# mongodb filter child list and parents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have Tasks and actions that related to task
I want to get all the tasks each task with related action

But the task's active field need to be true and the action's active field need to be true
in addition I want get the task just if there is at least 1 action related to the task
if there is no action related I do not want show this task

This is my Query for now

```
    const tasks= await Task.aggregate([
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "actions",
                    localField: "_id" ,
                    foreignField: "task",
                    as: "actions",
                  }
            },
            {$match: {
                group: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(groupId),
                active:true,
                "actions.active":true
                }
            },              
   ]).exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `$match` twice and `$lookup` with pipeline:

```
const tasks= await Task.aggregate([
  {$match: {group: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(groupId), active: true}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "actions",
      let: {id: "$_id"},
      as: "actions",
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {
            $and: [
              {active: true},
              {$expr: {$eq: ["$task", "$$id"]}}
            ]
        }},
        {$project: {_id: 1}}
      ]
  }},
  {$match: {"actions.0": {$exists: true}}},
  {$unset: "actions"}
]).exec()
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/s_3K7CNjzWS)

Comment: What this is mean   {$unset: "companies"}

Comment: I edited the answer, it is now removing all the `actions` that you added, if you don't need them in your answer. If you do need them. you can remove this line

Comment: @nimrodserok, `$unset` removes the extra wrapper object if there is any, ex: `a: [ {} ]` becomes: `a: {}`